# how to merge two or more tables sorted according to date

Tags: mysql, database-design

hello pls i need help on my school project. I have tables try1 and try2, i want to join the two showing the income and expenditure sorted with the date accordingly from the try1 and try2

```
try1
         +------+-------+--------+--------+
         |  id  | date  | name   |expensis|
         +------+-------+--------+--------+
         |  1   |17/11/1|  shoe  |   200  |
         +------+-------+--------+--------+
         |  2   |17/11/2|  books |   300  |
         +------+-------+--------+--------+
         |  3   |17/11/2| T.fair |   400  |
         +------+-------+--------+--------+
```

```
try2
         +------+-------+--------+--------+
         |  id  | date  | name   | source |
         +------+-------+--------+--------+
         |  1   |17/11/1|  Dad   |  1000  |
         +------+-------+--------+--------+
         |  2   |17/11/2| uncle  |        |
         +------+-------+--------+--------+
         |  3   |17/11/4|  Bro   | 150    |
         +------+-------+--------+--------+
```

this is how i want my table to look like

```
   
    RESULT
             +-------+--------+--------+
             | date  |expensis| source |
             +-------+--------+--------+
             |17/11/1|  200   |  1000  |
             +-------+--------+--------+
             |17/11/2|  300   |        |
             +-------+--------+--------+
             |17/11/2|  400   |        |
             +-------+--------+--------+
             |17/11/4|        |  150   |
             +-------+--------+--------+
```

i tried many codes and it didnt work out this is the code somewhat  close to what i want

```
 
SELECT u.date, b.amount, h.amount
FROM
  (SELECT Date FROM try1 UNION SELECT Date FROM try2) u
  RIGHT JOIN try1 b ON u.Date=b.Date
 RIGHT JOIN try2 h ON u.Date=h.Date
```

EDIT: ddl and sample data

```
CREATE TABLE try1 
( id int(2) AUTO_INCREMENT
, date date
, name varchar(10)
, expencis double(10,0)
,     PRIMARY KEY(id) );

CREATE TABLE try2 
( id int(2) AUTO_INCREMENT
, date date
, name varchar(10)
, sourcee int(10)
,     PRIMARY KEY(id) );

INSERT into try1 (date,name,expencis)
VALUES ('2017-11-1','shoe',200)
     , ('2017-11-2','books',300)
     , ('2017-11-2','t.fair',400);

INSERT into try2 (date,name,sourcee)
VALUES ('2017-11-1','dad',1000)
     , ('2017-11-2','uncle',null)
     , ('2017-11-4','bro',null);
```

Comment: I recommend you see [how do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to create a minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), then come back and update your question accordingly; in particular, provide the `create table` and `insert` commands for your sample data, the join criteria, and also provide the query(s) you've tried so far; you need to put some (more) effort into your question and show us what you've tried so far ... we're not here to do your homework for you

Comment: i am not good in english i am using a translator to write this that is the challange i have; the code i tried:   SELECT u.date, b.amount, h.amount
FROM
  (SELECT Date FROM try1 UNION SELECT Date FROM try2) u
  RIGHT JOIN try1 b ON u.Date=b.Date
 RIGHT JOIN try2 h ON u.Date=h.Date

Comment: Double-check the documentation on `JOIN`s. In a right join, the table on the right side of the join will be included regardless of whether or not there's a match; the table on the left side will be ignored *except* where it matches the table on the right. I believe you'd want the date (the left table) regardless of whether or not `try1` or `try2` has a match (at least one will, of course).

Comment: @JoshuaSampson - Did you try replace your `RIGHT JOIN`s with `LEFT JOIN`s, as I suggested?

Comment: @RDFozz wow EPIC!! u made my day...i now understanded more about Joins . i start learning and practicing MYSQL 3weeks ago thanks for your great contribute .I realy appreciate all the efforts

Comment: Next thing to note: you probably want to join subqueries instead of `try1` and `try2`, instead of the tables directly. If you had two entries with the same date in `try1`, and one with that date in `try2`, then the `try2` row would be match with both `try1` rows, and that amount would show up twice. `SELECT Date, SUM(amount) as amount FROM try1 GROUP BY Date` will make sure you've only got one row from the table for any given date.

Comment: wow please @ RDFozz that is exactly what am facing right now you are an Angel.. can you give me a sample code??  i am a novist. Since i can now sort the records according to date,some records show up twice.I will be gratefull ,thanks. Here is the link  https://qlfiddle.com/#!9/b67055/1  please see how you can help me out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not entirely sure that I understand your problem, but it appears as if you are looking for a `FULL OUTER JOIN`. I don't think that is supported by MySQL, but you can mimic the result by doing a union between a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` and a `RIGHT OUTER JOIN`:

```
select t1.date, t1.expencis, t2.sourcee 
from try1 t1 
left join try2 t2 
    on t1.date = t2.date 
union 
select t2.date, t1.expencis, t2.sourcee 
from try1 t1 
right join try2 t2 
    on t1.date = t2.date 
order by date

+------------+----------+---------+
| date       | expencis | sourcee |
+------------+----------+---------+
| 2017-11-01 |      200 |    1000 |
| 2017-11-02 |      300 |    NULL |
| 2017-11-02 |      400 |    NULL |
| 2017-11-04 |     NULL |    NULL |
+------------+----------+---------+
```

Note that order by is applied after union.
For future posts, never use ascii tables like above. Provide `CREATE TABLE` statements and `INSERT` statements instead. Your question will likely get more attention, and you will get better answers that way.

Comment: when i run the code  under `expencis` i have 200,200,200,300,400 null and under source i have 1000,0,150,300,300,400 i dont know why

Comment: Beats me, I can't run the query since I neither have table definitions nor sample data.

Comment: but its not working please do help me,create the tables and insert the records into them and see how you can help me out please

Comment: I might do that if you provide table definitions (`CREATE TABLE try1 ( ... )`, ...) and some sample data (`INSERT INTO try1 (...) VALUES ( ... )` ).

Comment: CREATE TABLE try1 (
    id int(2) AUTO_INCREMENT,
    date date,
    name varchar(10),
    expencis double(10,0),
     PRIMARY KEY(id)
);
CREATE TABLE try2 (
    id int(2) AUTO_INCREMENT,
    date date,
    name varchar(10),
    sourcee int(10),
    PRIMARY KEY(id)
);


INSERT into try1 (date,name,expencis)VALUES("2017-11-1",'shoe',200),
("2017-11-2",'books',300),
("2017-11-2",'t.fair',400);

INSERT into try2 (date,name,sourcee)VALUES("2017-11-1",'dad',1000),
("2017-11-2",'uncle',' '),
("2017-11-4",'bro',' ');

Comment: i have the posted the code to create the both tables and inserted into it

Comment: With the exception that sourcee in your sample data is null for 4/11, the result of the query is what you asked for in your question

Comment: thank you so much sir,i really appretiated this.... i am sorry for my bad English